# How to prove that the determinant of a square matrix is the product of its singular values?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a square matrix of order $n$.
I need to prove $|A| = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i$ where $\sigma_i$ denotes a singular value.

I know that the SVD decomposition of $A$ is $A=U.\sum.V^*$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices and thus their determinants have absolute value 1.

So this gives me $|A|=1.|\sum|.1$ and $|A|=-1.|\sum|.-1$, which gives me what I need to prove.

But what about the case when $|U|=-1$ and $|V^*|=1$ or vice versa?

Comment: What are the singular values of the $1\times1$ matrix , whose only  entry is $-1$?

Comment: Calculations suggest $i$?

Comment: My copy of the wikipedia suggests that singular values are non-negative real numbers.

Comment: Yes I know the same, which is why I’m confused...

Comment: What you want to prove is not always true.  The negative of the $k\times k$ identity matrix,  for odd $k$, is a counterexample.

Comment: Oh yes. In that case the singular values are all $1$, but the determinant of the matrix is $-1$?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.